# Creating a line graph with powerplot in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, graph

i'm using powerplot to create a dynamic graph in iphone. while going through http://www.field-theory.org/articles/powerplot/example.html i successfully create a graph, but i do not know how do i remove the default dec value inside the graph.
[image]

i will like to create something like this below, that i conceptualise from mockapps.

```
float sourceData[7] = {33, 17, 24, 11, 11, 4, 10};
    self.allData = [WSData dataWithValues:[WSData arrayWithFloat:sourceData withLen:7]];
self.allData = [self.allData indexedData];

WSChart *tmp;
tmp = [WSChart linePlotWithFrame:[aView frame]
                                 withData:self.allData
                                 withStyle:kChartLineFilled
                                 withAxisStyle:kCSGrid
                                 withColorScheme:kColorGray
                                 withLabelX:@"Days"
                                 withLabelY:@"Drinks"];
             [aView removeAllPlots];
             [aView addPlotsFromChart:tmp];

[aView scaleAllAxisYD:NARangeMake(-10, 45)];
[aView setAllAxisLocationYD:0];
[aView setAllAxisLocationXD:-0.5];  


WSPlotAxis *axis = [aView getPlotAxis];

[[axis ticksX] setTicksStyle:kTicksLabels];
[[axis ticksY] setTicksStyle:kTicksLabels];
[[axis ticksY] ticksWithNumbers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20],
                                 nil]
                     withLabels:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"",
                                 @"10%", @"20%", @"30%", nil]];

[axis.ticksX setTickLabelsWithStrings:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mon", @"Tue", @"Wed",
                                       @"Thur", @"Fri", @"Sat", @"Sun", nil]];



[aView setNeedsDisplay];
```

any comments are appreciated thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `linePlotWithFrame:...` method of `WSChart` generates two separate instances of `WSPlotAxis` on the plot-stack. The first instance is for the grid only, the second for the axis ticks and labels.

The method `WSPlotAxis *axis=[aView getPlotAxis]` will return the first view of type `WSPlotAxis` which does not have any tick labels initially. If you want to manually change the existing axis ticks and labels, you need to get the second instance by using

```
WSPlotAxis *axis = (WSPlotAxis *)[self.chart plotAtIndex:2].view;
```

instead of `WSPlotAxis *axis=[aView getPlotAxis];`.

Then it will work as expected.